# What Android platform to program to?

Tags: android

What Android platform should I program to? If I develop an app for Android 1.5, will it run on Android 2.2 or 2.3? If not, what should I do to make my app run on any platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, psychcio, if you develop an app for android 1.5, this will run on android 2.2 or 2.3.

Choosing a higher version platform depends on you want to use (or you need to) some new api, that doesn't exist on previous ones. In my experience, I used to develop for the minimum android version.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you set your target SDK to the most recent version of Android.  You then set your min SDK value to the oldest version of Android you wish to support (typically 1.5 or 1.6).

However, if you do this, **make sure you don't call any newer APIs found in newer versions (2.2, etc.) of Android that don't exist in older versions (1.5, 1.6, etc.).**

Comment: Or if you do want to call newer APIs on devices that support them, have a look at http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html :)